# how to get query value in array and show to label texts in sqlite xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, arrays, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am returning my query value in array like,

```
public IEnumerable<ItemTable> SearchItem(string itemName)
{
    return (from i in 
            _connection.Table<ItemTable>() 
            where i.ItemName.StartsWith(itemName) 
            select i).ToArray();      
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this array value when i call this function means how to get this result to show on screen on label's text. Please Reply

Comment: What values do you want to display in a label? What are the fields in ItemTable?

Comment: there are item Name and item Price in Item Table. I want to show these on label text using for each or other loop for all values

Comment: How does your code for xamarin form look like? In the above code you have an IEnumerable of `ItemTable`. I guess you know how to create a collection of name and price using that.

Comment: I do not know how to create a collection of name and price i am new to xamarin forms. Even i do not know that much about IEnumerable if you can clear me these things please help me ?

Comment: I cannot recommend you to learn C# using Xamarin. First try to learn the basic things using wpf. Have a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample;

```
    public IEnumerable<ItemTable> SearchItem(string itemName)
    {
        return (from i in
                _connection.Table<ItemTable>()
                where i.ItemName.StartsWith(itemName)
                select i).ToArray();
    }

    private string DisplayItemsInLabel(string itemName)
    {
        var searchedItems = this.SearchItem(itemName); // get items using above method that you have written already.

        // get name and price
        var displayableItems = searchedItems.Select(i => string.Format("Name :{0}, Price :{1}", i.Name, i.Price));

       // create a formatted string using name and the price. so that we can display it in a label.
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, displayableItems);
    }


    public LabelPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var layout = new StackLayout { Padding = new Thickness(5, 10) };
        this.Content = layout;

        //display contents in a label
        var label = new Label { Text = DisplayItemsInLabel("MyItem"), TextColor = Color.FromHex("#77d065"), FontSize = 20 };
        layout.Children.Add(label);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try this :)

Comment: Thanks @Kosala its working for me but i made some changes

Comment: var displayableItems = result.Select(i => i.ItemName);

           
            foreach(var item in displayableItems)
            {
                arrayStack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item, TextColor = Color.Black});
            }

Comment: You may upvote / accept this as the answer if it helped.